# Why is the <div> element not filling the rest of the screen wen I use height: 100%;

Tags: html, css

I am making a sidebar for my site and I want the side bar to fill the rest of the screen but also scroll separate to the right of the screen when it overflows with other elements inside. When I use 100% for the height the element only goes to the height of the last element inside of it.

I am trying to get it to fill the rest of the screen as I stated previously but it only goes to not all the way.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 345px;
  border: 0px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 450px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #404040;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.toptext {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 45px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.toptext h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  color: #404040;
}

.toptext p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  color: #404040;
}

.flexcolumn {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.leftmain {
  height: 100%;
  width: 325px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: #333333;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.leftmain p {
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 300px;
}

.leftmain p:hover {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #404040;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  align-content: center;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#test" id="nameOfCompany"> My Paper Company</a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <a href="#settings">Settings</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#donate">Donate</a>
    <div class="flexcolumn">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="leftmain" class="leftmain">
  <p id="button" div="leftmain" onclick='show("htpmain")'> How To Play</p>
</div>
<center>
  <div id=htpmain class="main">
    <div class="toptext">
      <h1>
         How To Play
      </h1>
      <p>This guide will get you start the game and will be helpful to grasp everything you need to do.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" />
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Side note, don't use `<center>`

Comment: What should I use instead

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Center_an_element

Comment: percentage heights are relative to their *parent* element's height, and also that only if it's defined. You can use `100vh` instead.

Comment: But doesn't leftmain not have a parent and when I use 100vh it make my page scroll able because I have a menu at the top

Answer (score 0):

Your leftmain IS taking up 100% of the space available to it, leftmain stops when it reaches . You have leftmain set to flex-direction: column;
when only the .main should have it. Also don't use the  tag, it is no longer supported in HTML5 and is display: block; when it should be inline-block.
I would change  just to  and set display to inline-block and set a width so the leftmain has room to go past it.
I hope this solves your problem.

```
.leftmain {
  height: 100%;
  width: 325px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: #333333;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#nameOfCenterDiv {
position: absolute;
left: 300px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This did not work

Comment: you can also do it manually by setting the leftmain height in px instead of %. you also have a <div> that has no ending tag, if you give it an ID and set that ID to have a negative  margin-top value

Answer (score 0):

Give to the sidebar a position fixed so it always stays there wherever you scroll and and a margin-left to your content on the right (the width of the margin-left must be the same of sidebar width)

```
.leftmain{
  position: fixed
}

.main{
margin-left: 345px;
width: 450px //remove this so it's 100%
}
```

Comment: No I want to do the opposite of what you said, I want it to stay in the original position on the page as you scroll not stay on the screen in the same spot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the left sidebar and right panel within the same container.
Using the `display: flex` on the container, you no longer need to specify a 100% height for the left sidebar since it will automatically fill in the remaining space.

You also need to remove the margin-left rule for the right content so that it lays nicely with the sidebar.

You can optionally set a `max-height` of `100vh` to the sidebar so that it scrolls when its content exceeds the viewport height.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.main {
  border: 0px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 450px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #404040;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.toptext {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 45px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.toptext h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  color: #404040;
}

.toptext p {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  color: #404040;
}

.flexcolumn {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.leftmain {
  width: 325px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: #333333;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.leftmain p {
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 300px;
}

.leftmain p:hover {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #404040;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  align-content: center;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#test" id="nameOfCompany"> My Paper Company</a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <a href="#settings">Settings</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#donate">Donate</a>
    <div class="flexcolumn">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div id="leftmain" class="leftmain">
  <p id="button" div="leftmain" onclick='show("htpmain")'> How To Play</p>
</div>
<center>
  <div id=htpmain class="main">
    <div class="toptext">
      <h1>
         How To Play
      </h1>
      <p>This guide will get you start the game and will be helpful to grasp everything you need to do.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card" />
  </div>
</center>
</div>
```